Problem with conditional: TF version working, but not the p version
I reused the code provided as an answer here (I tried to make it a new conditional)
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \if_font_exist:nnnn #1#2#3#4{p,T,F,TF}{
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_empty:nF{#1}{\fontencoding{#1}}
    \tl_if_empty:nF{#2}{\fontfamily{#2}}
    \tl_if_empty:nF{#3}{\fontseries{#3}}
    \tl_if_empty:nF{#4}{\fontshape{#4}}
    \try@load@fontshape
    \exp_args:No \if_meaning:w \cs:w \curr@fontshape \cs_end: \relax
        \group_end:
        \prg_return_true:
    \else:
        \tl_if_empty:nF{#1}{\fontencoding{#1}}
        \tl_if_empty:nF{#2}{\fontfamily{#2}}
        \tl_if_empty:nF{#3}{\fontseries{#3}}
        \tl_if_empty:nF{#4}{\fontshape{#4}}
        \selectfont
        \if_cs_exist:w  exfs@fake@\curr@fontshape \cs_end:
            \group_end:
            \prg_return_true:
        \else:
            \group_end:
            \prg_return_false:
        \fi:
    \fi:
}

What is strange is that the following seems to work fine
\if_font_exist:nnnnTF{T1}{RobotoSlab-TLF}{m}{n}{TRUE}{FALSE}

but the following fails:
\bool_lazy_or:nnTF{
    \if_font_exist_p:nnnn{T1}{RobotoSlab-TLF}{m}{n}
}{\c_false_bool}{T}{F}

with error:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \group_begin: 
l.203 }{\c_false_bool}
                      {T}{F}
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__bool_\group_begin:_0: 
l.203 }{\c_false_bool}
                      {T}{F}

QUESTIONS

What happens?
Why does it fail?
How to make it work?


The conditional you're defining is not expandable and cannot have a predicate version. You define it, but it's not a magic wand that makes unexpandable thing expandable.

And there is no way to tweak the code to make it expandable, I guess? What are the non-expandable functions?

Plenty, starting from \fontencoding and \try@load@fontshape.

\group_begin: and \group_end: aren't expandable either. Almost nothing you use there is expandable. The only bits that are are \tl_if_empty:nF, the two \if... tests, \prg_return_(true|false):, \else:, and \fi:.

Also notice that your \exp_args:No usage is wrong. You should use \exp_args:Nc \if_meaning:w { \curr@fontshape }.

@Skillmon With or without the relax after? What's the updated full line \exp_args:No \if_meaning:w \cs:w \curr@fontshape \cs_end: \relax

@Vincent \exp_args:Nc \if_meaning:w { \curr@fontshape } \relax

@Vincent you asked for a 'translation' of my code to expl3, but you did not say why you wanted to translate it. imho, that answer constitutes a case for the opposition rather than the defence ;). because the code relies on a bunch of 2e stuff which doesn't have (as far as I know) any expl3 interface, a translation into expl3 just obscures the code. I couldn't see any reason to do it. and I'm still not convinced there is one. ;)

@Skillmon the error is mine.

@Vincent the \relax is essential. you're comparing the meaning of two control sequences. the second is \relax. if the first means the same as \relax you do one thing; if not, you do the other. so any version of the code has to include \relax or some other cs with the same meaning.

The expl3 version of that \expandafter\ifx\csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax<true>\else<false>\fi would have been \cs_if_exist:cTF { \curr@fontshape } { <true> } { <false> }. same for the other test using \ifcsname exfs@fake@\curr@fontshape\endcsname <true>\else <false>\fi could just be replaced by \cs_if_exist:cTF (\cs_if_exist:cTF tests both, whether the control sequence does exist like \ifcsname, and whether it's unequal to \relax like \expandafter\ifx\csname ...\endcsname\relax).

@Skillmon that won't work at least for the second test because it needs to distinguish between non-existence and existence. it isn't enough to check (non-existence or \relax). if it exists at all, it will mean \relax.

@Skillmon that's why the tests are different in the original (non-expl3) code. (well, actually, also because they are completely separate tests in the original, but still.)
